# How to call a function with to parameters in mips32

Tags: mips32, qtspim

I have a function named `insertKey` that take as parameters an array address and a key. So I would like to call a function named `findKey` inside the function `insertKey` using the parameters of `insertKey`. The code in java is:

```
insertKey(int hash[],int k){
    int p;
    p = findKey(hash,k)
    //do some other things
}
```

So in my code the register `$a3` contains the address of the array and the register `$a1` contains the key. This is what I have done so far:

```
 main:
    lw $t1,$a3
    jal insertKey

insertKey:
    move $a0,$t1
```

But I don't know how to call `findkey` from `insertKey`. Can anyone help?

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) Why mentioning Java? 2) What exactly you don't understand? Where should the parameters go? How to make a call? There is a convention to use `$a0`-`$a4` to pass the first four parameters that can fit a register.

Comment: I am already using the register $a3 for the array adress . How can I pass it to the insertkey function.Then how can I call findKey with the same parameters ?

Comment: Can't you just do `add $a0, $0, $a3` to pass the array address to `insertKey`? In a nutshell, why can't you simply move values between registers? That's what I'm trying to understand from your question.